# undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState when importing tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

everyone!

I'm trying to install and run tensorflow (GPU-support). I followed the guide and installed cudnn 7 and cuda 9.0.

However, when trying to import tensorflow, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
disable=unused-import
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
<module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in 
swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, 
description)
ImportError: /home/boudi/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined 
symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you added /usr/local/cuda/lib64 to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, presuming you work on Ubuntu? If not, it cannot find the cuda libraries (though they are installed).

Comment: Hey Jan. Yes I have added the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it's: "/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - I had already installed the required NVIDIA drivers on my Ubuntu machine, but when I tried to import Tensorflow I got the same error.

So for me the problem was that I was using the Nouveau driver instead of the NVIDIA driver.  In order to fix the issue you need to go to `System Settings`->`Software & Updates`->`Additional Drivers` and select the option `Using NVIDIA binary driver ...` and then click at the `Apply Changes` button. Then just reboot and you're done.